# VueStoreFront: Custom module: state is updated, component not

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-storefront

I’m creating a custom module that fetches data in the “`afterRegistration`” hook and saves the result into the store.

The state is updated (can see the update in VueDevTools), but the component has still the default state. What I’m doing wrong?

```
// afterRegistration
export function afterRegistration ({Vue, config, store, isServer}) {
  store.dispatch(${KEY}/isVisible)
}

// component
export default {
  name: 'Test',
  components: { Fragment },
  props: {
   …
  },
  computed: {
    isVisible: el => el.$store.getters['myModule/simpleTest']
  }
}
```

Comment: In `computed` object, use `mapState` where you have to declare the state variable you need to use in your component

Answer (score 0):

You have lost the reactivity. Set the initial value of `simpleTest` in state object to whatever you like (from the context i see it's `Boolean`). There is no getter or setter for this field, if it's not in initial state.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that I need to dispatch in an AsyncLoader

```
// afterRegistration
export function afterRegistration ({Vue, config, store, isServer}) {
  AsyncDataLoader.push({
   execute: ({ route, store, context }) => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      store.dispatch(`${KEY}/getInlineTranslationConfig`)
        .then(() => resolve(null))
    })
  }
})
```

Now it works!